# Solution to interface SD card with microcontroller using only 2 pins (I2C/SPI)

Tags: stm32, i2c, spi, sd, bit-bang

So I am trying to add an [SD card](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/2005251034_XTX-XTSD04GLGEAG_C558839.pdf) to my circuit and unfortunately, all I have left are 4 GPIOs, but I was asked to try and find a solution to only use 2. So using 4 is a worst case scenario.
I thought about bit-banging SPI so that is one solution but ideally, I want to use 2 pins only so my guess is SPI is not possible and all is left is I2C bit-banging. I considered using an [I2C-SPI bridge](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/SC18IS602B.pdf) (speed is not a problem here), but memory is written in blocks of 512 bytes whereas the bridge sends 200 bytes at a time max.

Any solutions? If a 2-pin solution is not possible, what is the best solution using 4 pins?

Comment: How much space do you have available?

Comment: @BruceAbbott what do you mean by space?

Comment: I mean, what physical space do you have (on the PCB etc.) to add components.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I am not sure to be honest but that is not an issue here although the smaller the better of course

Comment: You *can* use that SCI18IS602B I2C-SPI bridge to send & receive 512-byte blocks. The trick would be to configure the SS pin to the SD card as a GPIO and control it 'manually' instead of letting the bridge IC control it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Driving an SD CARD with 2 pins is not possible.

Driving an SD CARD with 3 pins might be doable in 1-bit mode:

```
Pin 1  ->  CMD
Pin 2  ->  CLK
Pin 3  ->  DAT_0
```

Take a look here for more detailed info in 1-bit mode:

https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/Driver/html/group__mci__interface__gr.html

As far as I know 2-bit mode doesn't exist.